# Connecting to Postgresql with laradock in a docker

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, laradock

I have Postgresql on a server in a docker container. How can I connect to a database gui like tableplus so that i can run php artisan migrate, im also using laravel and how can i retrieve the database credentials of it, i tried the docker ps and this shows up

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES
2f68a5d257ee   laradock_postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   laradock_postgres_1

Comment: Retrieving credits: open the `.env` file of laradock and search for postgresql. There's a couple of entries, just keep searching. You'll end up with the db credentials. Enter those in your Laravel `.env` file. Running migrations: enter the `workspace` docker container: `docker-compose exec -it --user=laradock bash` and browse to your project. Then run the `php artisan migrate` command

Comment: Underdog should i replace that .env on my laravel using the .env on the laradock file?

Comment: i found this one: ### POSTGRES ##############################################

POSTGRES_VERSION=alpine
POSTGRES_CLIENT_VERSION=15
POSTGRES_DB=default
POSTGRES_USER=default
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./postgres/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in .env the host to point the container name.

keep the container up and running retrieve the postgres container name and .env should look:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres (or whatever value is the volume name in docker-compose.yml)
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Then you can interactively bash the container init the db and run migrations.